# How can I use geo location for predictive modelling

Tags: regression, feature-selection, linear-regression, geospatial

While determining the house price I don't want to throw away geo location as feature. At least I want to see if there is correlation. Geo-location is more like categorical variable. Is there a way to make it useful feature

Comment: head over to kaggle's NYC Taxi Comp

Comment: Which type of model(s) are you using in your analysis? Linear regression and decision tree models can work with categorical variables as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why is it categorical? You can use the longitude / latitude numeric coordinates as two features.